# can i use non-generic protocols in kubernetes service annotations

Tags: kubernetes

Can I use t3 protocol in kubernetes services, like we use jdbc protocol in kubernetes annotations, e.g.

```
annotations:
    api.service.kubernetes.io/scheme: t3
    api.service.kubernetes.io/protocol: t3
```

Comment: I don't think kubernetes supports this kind of annotation see any reference in the kubernetes documentation.

Comment: I'm sure kubernetes support these annotation,because I'm able to create k8s service successfully for jdbc protocol but not for t3 protocol